# как взять отдельное значение поля модели django/python

Tags: python, django

Например, есть статьи и оригинальные ссылки на них. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку "читать" и переходит на другую страницу. Как взять url именно той статьи, на которую нажал пользователь и сделать запрос для парсинга

пример модели

```
class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=250) #ссылка на оригинальную статью
```

Comment: `Test.objects.filter(title='my book').last().link`

Comment: в целом то, что надо, но если я не знаю на кнопку для какой статьи нажмет пользователь?